# Docker commands take ~10 seconds to run when not connected to domain

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker on a Windows 10 computer that is joined to a domain.  When I'm at work and connected to the domain, Docker runs fine.  However, when I'm at home, simple Docker commands like `docker images` or `docker --help` sometimes run within a second, and sometimes take 10 seconds or so.  This problem continues to occur even if I connect to my corporate VPN at home.

The few posts that I've seen talking about this issue suggest that it's a problem with DNS timeouts, but I'm not sure how to resolve that.

I tried running Process Explorer to monitor `docker.exe`.  Each time I run a Docker command, I see Process Explorer saying `BAD NETWORK PATH` for the path `\\MYDOMAIN\PIPE\samr` once my command completes after the ~10 second delay.

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed further to fix this.  I've seen some people suggest editing my hosts file to point to 127.0.0.1 for anything that Docker is trying to access on my domain, but I'm not sure how to do that for a pipe.  Is there anything I can do to try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this only:

tldr: try adding this line to your local hosts file:

```
254.254.254.254  MYDOMAIN
```

For details, see https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1936#issuecomment-436010920

Another useful thread may this one be:
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2131

UPDATE:
For the reasons listed above, I tried to set Docker under Docker Desktop / Settings / Resources / Manual DNS Configuration to use DNS server `8.8.8.8` and this solved this `docker` command execution latency issue for me:

[image: Docker Desktop DNS settings]